# How to make fixed variable dynamic? (Pine script)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How to make a = 31 work from 0 to 100? that is, a = 0, 1, 2, ...., 99, 100. The option a1 = 0, a2 = 1, etc. is the wrong option. Maybe there is a function or group of functions that will allow you to do this. Can't find information.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Stochastic", shorttitle="Stoch", overlay = true, format=format.price, precision=2, max_bars_back=1000)
periodK = input.int(14, title="%K Length", minval=1)
smoothK = input.int(3, title="%K Smoothing", minval=1)
periodD = input.int(3, title="%D Smoothing", minval=1)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = int(ta.sma(k, periodD))
//plot(k, title="%K", color=#2962FF)
plot(d, title="%D", color=#FF6D00)
plot(31, '1', color.yellow)

a = 31

bool isCond1 = ta.cross(d, a)

if isCond1
    label.new(bar_index, 1, text = 'cros')
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to display the data when D% crosses a, I developed the code when a=31, but I don't know how to make a =(0:100) so here I presented a simple code model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to do that.

But after, you will have a problem because using `ta.croos`in a local block will give you false value.

So you need to replace ta.cross with logical test :
This test is true if the serie a and d crossed :

```
isCond1 = (d[1]<a and d>a) or (d[1]>a and d<a) or (d<(a-1) and d>a) or (d>a-1 and d<a)
```

The complete code is :

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Stochastic", shorttitle="Stoch", overlay = true, format=format.price, precision=2, max_bars_back=1000, max_labels_count = 500)
periodK = input.int(14, title="%K Length", minval=1)
smoothK = input.int(3, title="%K Smoothing", minval=1)
periodD = input.int(3, title="%D Smoothing", minval=1)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = int(ta.sma(k, periodD))
//plot(k, title="%K", color=#2962FF)
plot(d, title="%D", color=#FF6D00)
plot(31, '1', color.yellow)

    for a = 0 to 100
        isCond1 = (d[1]<a and d>a) or (d[1]>a and d<a) or (d<(a-1) and d>a) or (d>a-1 and d<a)
        if isCond1
            label.new(bar_index, 1, text = 'cross '+str.tostring(a) )
```

[image]

Comment: Cool!!!!! There are no words!